# How to make cell reference from string without using indirect function [Excel]

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have list of named ranged with full path which is going to change each month.
I have one "master" workbook that pulls data from several workbooks(in first picture below,they are named file1,file2...). It works fine when the woorkbooks from which datas are pulled are open, but not when they are closed. On the other hand if I link cells directly(see the second picture), my master workbook is able to pull data from closed workbooks(file1,file2...). What I need is to have something like this

> =concatenate(Fullpath,CurrentMonth,cell)
>
> === 'C:\Users\do803281\Desktop\test WD\1\[OD.xlsx]OD'!G12 to be taken as cell reference.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ti711v20cdb903/Screenshot%202014-08-06%2014.47.19.png
https://www.dropbox.com/s/8k4whk8fhey3x8c/Screenshot%202014-08-06%2014.58.42.png

Comment: What's wrong with `indirect(concatenate(Fullpath,CurrentMonth,cell))`

Comment: it does not work when the workbooks are closed, on the other hand if cells are linked directly AND workbooks are closed the data can be updated without a problem. I apologize if I did not express myself clearly, I do not speak English very well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated **INDIRECT does not work if the source workbook is closed**

But there is a solution:

get Morefunc addon and use `=INDIRECT.EXT()` function, which works with closed workbooks.

---

**MOREFUNC ADDON**

- here is the last working [download link](http://www.freewarefiles.com/downloads_counter.php?programid=14922) I found
- here is a good [installation walk-through video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TAofPm4LCRc#t=92)